# Export from PostgreSQL multiple times to same file

Tags: postgresql, csv, append

Is it possible to export a table to csv, but to append multiple selections to the same file?

I would like to export  (for instance):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a > 5
```

Then, later:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE b > 2
```

This must go to the same file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of to do this is from the command-line, redirecting output.

```
psql -d dbname -t -A -F"," -c "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a > 5" >> output.csv
```

then later

```
psql -d dbname -t -A -F"," -c "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE b > 2" >> output.csv
```

You can look up the command line options here.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `\o <filename>` to output to a file. All your `SELECT` statements after using `\o` will be appended to `<file>` until you set `\o` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\o` in combination with `\copy` to STDOUT seems to work. For example:

```
db=> \o /tmp/test.csv
db=> \copy (select 'foo','bar') to STDOUT with CSV;
db=> \copy (select 'foo','bar') to STDOUT with CSV;
db=> \q

$ cat /tmp/test.csv 
foo,bar
foo,bar
```